# Printing out standard C/GCC predefined macros in terminal

Tags: gcc

I am wondering if there is a way to simply output to the terminal the value of some global/standard definitions of C/GCC, e.g. using the `echo` command, without writing C code and using `printf`?

I mean things like `__GNUC_`, `__UINT64_MAX__`, `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can view the value of any defined constant as follows:

```
echo __GNUC__ | gcc -E -
```

If you need to add an include file:

```
echo O_APPEND | gcc -include fcntl.h -E -
```

Answer (score 2):

```
gcc -E file.c
```

Will do what you want it to. It's a good idea to browse it's manual, as assembly output is possible as well, not to mention lots of other features.