# Where do you find the syscall table for Linux?

Tags: syscalls

I see a lot of people online referencing

```
arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl
```

for the syscall table, that works fine. But a lot of others reference

```
/include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h
```

which is commonly found in the headers package. How come `syscall_64.tbl` shows,

```
0 common  read      sys_read
```

The right answer, and `unistd.h` shows,

```
#define __NR_io_setup 0
__SC_COMP(__NR_io_setup, sys_io_setup, compat_sys_io_setup)
```

And then it shows `__NR_read` as

```
#define __NR_read 63
__SYSCALL(__NR_read, sys_read)
```

Why is that 63, and not 1? How do I make sense of out of `/include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h`? Still in `/usr/include/asm/` there is

```
/usr/include/asm/unistd_x32.h
#define __NR_read (__X32_SYSCALL_BIT + 0)
#define __NR_write (__X32_SYSCALL_BIT + 1)
#define __NR_open (__X32_SYSCALL_BIT + 2)
#define __NR_close (__X32_SYSCALL_BIT + 3)
#define __NR_stat (__X32_SYSCALL_BIT + 4)

/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h
#define __NR_read 0
#define __NR_write 1
#define __NR_open 2
#define __NR_close 3
#define __NR_stat 4

/usr/include/asm/unistd_32.h
#define __NR_restart_syscall 0
#define __NR_exit 1           
#define __NR_fork 2           
#define __NR_read 3           
#define __NR_write 4
```

Could someone tell me the difference between these `unistd` files. Explain how `unistd.h` works? And what the best method for finding the syscall table?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When I’m investigating this kind of thing, I find it useful to ask the compiler directly (see [Printing out standard C/GCC predefined macros in terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/254698/86440) for details):

```
printf SYS_read | gcc -include sys/syscall.h -E -
```

This shows that the headers involved (on Debian) are `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/syscall.h`, `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd.h`, `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_64.h`, and `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/syscall.h`, and prints the system call number for `read`, which is 0 on x86-64.

You can find the system call numbers for other architectures if you have the appropriate system headers installed (in a cross-compiler environment). For 32-bit x86 it’s quite easy:

```
printf SYS_read | gcc -include sys/syscall.h -m32 -E -
```

which involves `/usr/include/asm/unistd_32.h` among other header files, and prints the number 3.

So from the userspace perspective, 32-bit x86 system calls are defined in `asm/unistd_32.h`, 64-bit x86 system calls in `asm/unistd_64.h`. `asm/unistd_x32.h` is used for the [x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI).

`uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h` lists the default system calls, which are used on architectures which don’t have an architecture-specific system call table.

In the kernel the references are slightly different, and are architecture-specific (again, for architectures which don’t use the generic system call table). This is where files such as `arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl` come in (and they ultimately end up producing the header files which are used in user space, `unistd_64.h` etc.). You’ll find a lot more detail about system calls in the pair of LWN articles on the topic, [Anatomy of a system call part 1](https://lwn.net/Articles/604287/) and [Anatomy of a system call part 2](https://lwn.net/Articles/604515/).

Comment: Is the syscall table stable between Linux kernel version and future ones?

Comment: @Biswapriyo it is, that’s part of the ABI stability which the kernel developers always try to preserve. New syscalls can be added, but old ones don’t change, except in a very small number of extreme cases (such as [the `tux` syscall](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446507/86440)).

Answer (score 20):

**Different archs have different syscall numbers defined in different files**

The syscall numbers are different for each architecture, e.g.:

- x86_64: [`arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.17/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl#L11): read is 0
- x86: [`arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.17/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl#L17): read is 3
- arm64: [`include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.17/include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h#L203): read is 63, see also: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16917/arm64-syscalls-table/18834#18834
- arm: [`arch/arm/tools/syscall.tbl`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.17/arch/arm/tools/syscall.tbl#L17), read is 3

**`include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h` vs `arch/*` definitions**

I think that `include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h` is a newer attempt at unifying syscall numbers across all archs.

But since syscall numbers cannot change to not break the syscall API, older archs before that unification effort (including x86, x86_64 and arm) have kept the old numbers defined under `arch/`. arm64 is newer, and got the new `unistd.h` API however.

This related question asks for an automated way of getting the full syscall list including parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604007/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-linux-system-calls-and-number-of-args-they-take-automati

**`strace` source code**

I trust that tool, and they keep their data tidy under `linux/`, e.g.:

- x86_64: https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/v4.26/linux/x86_64/syscallent.h
- aarch64: https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/27739ebccc96c0f70cd2aeb37fd7b0ecfef21724/linux/aarch64/syscallent.h

Note that the aarch64 one `#include`s the arch agnostic [`64/syscallent.h`](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/27739ebccc96c0f70cd2aeb37fd7b0ecfef21724/linux/64/syscallent.h) which I referred to earlier.

Those tables contain the number of arguments, but not actual argument types, I wonder where `strace` encodes them.

**`glibc` source code**

- x86_64: https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/glibc-2.35/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64/arch-syscall.h#L231

Answer (score 12):

I have a page which lists all system calls for each Linux supported architecture:

https://marcin.juszkiewicz.com.pl/download/tables/syscalls.html

Answer (score 9):

To add on all the great answers, there is a utility [`ausyscall`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ausyscall) which can be used to list all the syscalls and their integer mappings for the particular architecture.

eg:

```
$ ausyscall --dump
Using x86_64 syscall table:
0   read
1   write
2   open
3   close
4   stat
...
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer will not touch on the `asm-generic` version of `unistd.h`, because nothing includes it.<sup>1</sup>

As noted in `syscalls(2)`:

> Roughly speaking, the code belonging to the system call with number __NR_xxx defined in `/usr/include/asm/unistd.h` can be found in the Linux kernel source in the routine `sys_xxx`().

That is, the correct syscall numbers will be found in `/usr/include/asm/unistd.h`. Now, on a typical x86 system, this will simply include one of the `asm/unistd_*.h` files depending on the target.

The syscall numbers appropriate for a 64-bit program are in `asm/unistd_64.h`, and those for a 32-bit program in `asm/unistd_32.h` (or the nearly-equivalent `_x32.h` variant). The two are different because the 32- and 64-bit architectures are, effectively, completely different operating systems. They share the same set of syscalls, but not in the same order, for various reasons.

Most of these have C-language wrappers as well, so rarely will you need to use `syscall(2)` directly.

---

<sup>1</sup> And because I don't know what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

I too have a page that lists linux syscalls: https://syscalls.defoy.tech/

You will get the parameters for each of them. The script actually doing the work uses both the syscall table files (*.tbl) and the unistd headers (depending on the architecture). It runs every week so the data should always be up to date.

There are other sources too:

- https://syscalls.w3challs.com/ (you'll get the parameters too, but it is not up to date and all the links are dead)
- https://syscall.sh/about (it does not handle many architectures but it has an API if you need it)

Like Ciro, I think the strace source code provides the most reliable syscall lists. However they do not centralize the prototypes in the syscallent headers. The parameters are encoded in custom-made handler functions for each syscall.