# What did the system call "tuxcall" do?

Tags: linux, system-calls

In `include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_64.h`, I see a system call named `tuxcall`,

```
#define __NR_tuxcall 184
```

There is nothing about it in `man tuxcall` except to say that it's an *unimplemented system calls*. What did it do? Was it never implemented, or did it do something in antiquity?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`tuxcall` is the place-holder for [the `tux` system call](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/2-tux/) which was used by user-space tools to communicate with the TUX kernel module, which implemented the [TUX web server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUX_web_server). This was a web server running entirely in the kernel; it was maintained by Ingo Molnar until improvements in other parts of Linux, notably thread support with [NPTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library), brought user-space web server performance up to the level attained by TUX.

You can still find the TUX 3 patches for Linux 2.6.18 among [Ingo’s patches](http://people.redhat.com/~mingo/TUX-patches/), including the implementation of `sys_tux` (the system call in question). The user-space portion, which includes the documentation, can be found on [the Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20050831044744/http://people.redhat.com/~mingo/TUX-patches/) (thanks [hvd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/56650/hvd)!).

Answer (score 15):

I've found something from [non-standard-syscalls](https://www.linux.org/threads/non-standard-syscalls.10192/):

> **tuxcall()** - This call comes from a TUX module and is sent to the
>   kernel. The call asks the kernel to perform some task for the module.
>   A TUX module is basically a server application/daemon in the form of a
>   Linux module. Imagine an Apache server being a kernel module; that is
>   essentially how TUX works.